# MySQL Database Structure for Time Based Chart and Report Generation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design, charts

My application will allow users to like or dislike a product and leave a short feedback. I have to make a functionality which will show graph and produce report based on different time frame, probably it will be yearly, monthly, weekly and daily basis.

I have to show how many users liked or disliked the product on a particular time duration via a chart and generate the report. So my application should able to produce the **daily graph of August 2018** or **monthly graph of year 2018** of a particular product. The graph should able to reveal how many users liked or disliked the product on daily basis if it is daily graph, Similarly it may be for weekly, monthly or yearly time frame

I am not sure what should be the database structure for this type of application? Here what I have thought so far.

```
products: id, name, descp...etc // products table

users: id, name, email ...etc // users table

user_reactions: id, user_id(foreign key), product_id(foreign key), action(liked or disliked, tinyint), feedback // user_reactions table

data: id, product_id(foreign key), date(Y-m-d), total_like, total_dislike. // data table, will be used to make graph and report
```

What, I am thinking is that, I will run a cron job on 23:59:59 every day to count the like and dislike of each product and will add the data in last table, i.e. `data` table as mentioned above and then will use this `data` table to make graph and report. I am not sure if this database structure is correct or it have some unseen problem (may be in future?)

**Note:** My Application will be in `PHP` and `MySQL`

Comment: Hi. There is no question in this post. When you edit it to ask one, it it should be appropriate. [ask] [mcve] Ask one question per post.

Comment: So far so good.  Write out the actual `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statements and `SELECTs`.  Then see if you need to ask further.

Answer (score 0):

Well, There is no right answer to your question. Because an answer to your question is called an opinion based answer. You and I will get enough downvotes for sure . But still, hear me out my friend because I was in your state once.

There is a quote by famous professor Mr. Donald Knuth

**Premature optimization is the root of all evil**

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.

The idea is that you have to start building. as your application progress, you will face troubles, you will face problems with your database, your system might not scale or it can't handle a million requests. But until you hit that problem you don't have to worry about it.

I am not saying that you should go and build a system blindly with an infinite loop, or create a table join which can cause deadlocks. I hope you get my point.

Build a system with your knowledge and understanding. Because there is no one straight way to a problem. **build a feature -> you hit an issue -> tweak your app ->  and rinse and repeat.** One day your own experiences will show you the right path.

From your given description I can't figure out exactly how it will come out, but I am sure it will suffice for your initial days. As you progress, you might find it hard to add new features or add additional constraints, But its another day. wait for it and ask another question.

I hope I have answered your question.

Comment: Hi. No answer should contain any of "There is no right answer to your question. Because an answer to your question is called an opinion based answer. You and I will get enough downvotes for sure . But still," or be posted while it is true. These are reasons to downvote, close vote & comment. [answer]